# In javafx tableview, format a cell depending on an external value

Tags: javafx

I am building a JavaFX application. The application visualises time series data. I have a table showing, for example, the price of gold in 2001. The user wants to compare this with the price in 2007, or some other year which she selects.

I would like to format the table cell so that, if the price in 2007 has changed beyond that in 2001, by a magnitude that exceeds a given margin, it will get a different colour.

The data model for the table is an Observable list. Each item in the observable list instantiates a quite simple class such as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "commodity")
@XmlRootElement
public class Commodity {
    private StringProperty commodityName;
    private DoubleProperty unitPrice;
    private DoubleProperty unitValue;
}
```

I am trying to devise a strategic approach to this question. I'm quite new to JavaFx.

I'm considering the following:

(1) simply create a copy, within the Commodity class, of every member, thus:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "commodity")
@XmlRootElement
public class Commodity {
    private StringProperty commodityName;
    private DoubleProperty price;
    private StringProperty comparatorCommodityName;
    private DoubleProperty comparatorPrice;
}
```

Populate this from persistent entities for the current year and the comparator year. For example if the current year is 2016, price will be the price of 2016 and if the comparator year is 2011, comparatorPrice will be the price of 2011.

Then create a CellFactory for each column (commodityName, price, etc) that will ask if

```
price - comparatorPrice > threshold
```

for some threshold defined by the app and the user. I don't like this because it's not abstract; every CellFactory has to be crafted singly.

(2) in some way, make the members of the Commodity class more complex, so they carry with them the information needed to decide whether they have changed. I thought of extending the Property classes but that seems difficult, because they are interfaces and as far as I can see, to create a new Property class would involve implementing all the methods of the interface. I am not too familiar with interfaces so I may have misunderstood the underlying technology.

(3) use Maps; make the underlying model a MapValue model. I haven't explored this, but the idea would be that the cell data for a given row and column would be a Map, in which the Commodity object itself would be the key to retrieve another object, its comparator

(4) add a new member to the Commodity class being the comparator:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "commodity")
@XmlRootElement
public class Commodity {
    private StringProperty commodityName;
    private DoubleProperty price;
    private StringProperty comparatorCommodityName;
    private DoubleProperty comparatorPrice;
    private Commodity comparator = null;
    public void setComparator(Commodity comparator){
         this.comparator=comparator;
    }
    public Comparator getComparator(){
         return comparator;
    }
}
```

The CellFactory would then need to interrogate the base entity and its comparator member, to decide how to format the cell. This is not very abstract, because code would have to be written for each member, but at least it would create some kind of standard.

I don't find any of these options very satisfactory, which makes me wonder if somebody has done this before, and I just need to learn more JavaFX.

I hope this question does not have a scope that is too broad. The problem is quite specific.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to style an entire row instead of a single cell. In this case, I suggest using `RowFactory`.

Comment: It is a single cell that needs to be styled - just the changed item. it looks like a row because I only specified one column in the example given, for simplicity. But in general a commodity has several numerical properties, eg stock exchange quotations, and each could in principle have its own column. We would only style the cells in those columns where the data have changed.

Comment: I successfully implemented using strategy (4). It works but it feels clunky because every column needs a cell factory that is specific to the member it displays, but the problem is generic ["did this number change?].

Comment: So, if you are only trying to style one cell, why do you need `CellFactory`s on every column? You should only need it for that column.

Comment: Hi, because all of them change. Or rather, might change. I need to flag the ones that have changed.

Comment: Then you'll need to use a separate `CellFactory` for each Column, unless they all change in the same way, then you could use one `CellFacotry` and apply them to each column.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem like it. In fact that is what I have done. It's a pain because with six columns, for example, I need six longish CellFactory methods, which are identical in almost all respects. This, it seems to me, calls for some more abstract approach. 

I will try to post a stripped-down example showing my usage. This might help.